# How to generate sha1 hashes of a whole dvd?

Tags: checksums

How can I generate one text-file containing all sha1 hashes of all files on a dvd with many folders and subfolders?

Answer (score 2):

Use `find`

```
find /path/to/DVD -exec sha1sum {} + > text.file
```

Comment: could you please explain the parameters being passed to sha1sum? i mean how does `'{}' \;` work

Comment: Thank you Oli. astrob0t - -exec passes the file to a command, sha1sum, and the {} represent the file, + or \; continues to next file. the find command has a number of options and can seem complex, See http://content.hccfl.edu/pollock/Unix/FindCmd.htm for a great intro

Comment: @astrob0t That's just how `find` substitutes the files it finds into commands. I've actually switched out `{} \;` for `{} +`. Instead of running `sha1sum file1; sha1sum file2 ...` it runs `sha1sum file1 file2 ...`. Only works when the command can take multiple files like that but makes things faster.